# Help with a project in Control Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, control-theory

I have to develop a project in a Control Theory course along the semester. The problem is that we just started the semester so I don't know any about control theory haaha, so I post this here to ask you for ideas. The project has no clear requirements, but past projects include solving a concrete problem, investigation about stochastic and discrete extensions of some of the tools seen along the year and applications on game theory.

Also, in general, I like functional analysis and algebra.

The contents that we will see along the semester are:

-Linear systems, controllability, observability, stability, etc

-Quadratic linear problem.

-Pontryagin maximum principle

-Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equations

If you need more information please say it.

PD: sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

Comment: Why not ask your instructor for recommendation?

Comment: He was going to present some ideas but it never happend.

Comment: up up up up up u

Comment: Especially since you're also covering optimal control in your course, you can find problems in pretty much any application, so maybe start with: what concrete issues are you interested in?

And maybe if you give a concrete example of where functional analysis and algebra pop up in the real world, that would help pick a concrete problem.

Comment: (1/2) I know few facts about this subject (I am not a professor), next book seems that covers some of your topics, you can find it from the web of Dover Publications: J. R. Leigh, *Functional Analysis and Linear Control Theory*, Dover Publications (2007). Always you can search special issues as *what's the Hamilton–Jacobi–Bellman equation* in Google, for example there is a Wikipedia's article dedicated to this equation, or different lecture notes or books explaining for example the direct method in the calculus of variations...as companion of your books. I've found the following paper, it can

Comment: (2/2) be interesting to know what's the control theory:  E. Fernández-Cara and E. Zuazua, *Control Theory: History, Mathematical Achievements and Perspectives*. Bol. Soc. Esp. Mat. Apl. **26**, (2003), 79-140.  Finally if you search in Google keywords as, for example: *Hamilton–Jacobi–Bellman equation, game theory, pdf* or *Hamilton–Jacobi–Bellman equation, control theory, pdf* you should find course notes or lectures notes that you can to explore and read to know more sources.  The best idea is that you ask to your professor what is your way to write an original work at the end of your course

Answer (score 0):

Looking for hot topic?

How about fractional-order PID?

Refs: 
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-order_control), [blog](http://fomcon.net/tutorial-fractional-order-pid-controller-design-for-a-system-with-input-output-delay/), [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0144.pdf), [paper](http://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/prost/proceedings/acc09/data/papers/1371.pdf)